# Ubuntu and Matplotlib

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib

Hello I am using the Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS (HVM), SSD Volume Type instance from amazon aws and I am running python 2.7.9 and the latest version of matplotlib. I am trying to plot the sine function and then save the figure to a png in the home directory. Below is my code:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('AGG')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0,2*np.pi,100)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.savefig('Sine')
```

after I save the figure I use WinSCP to move the png file to my local desktop so that I can open it. But when I open the file I only see the black box with x and y tick marks.

Am I just using the wrong backend, or is the problem egregiously more severe?

Comment: Why don't you try without modifying the backend?

Comment: I have, and I get the error " : no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable "

Comment: Well then have you considered trying different backends?

Comment: Yes I have, I have tried Cairo,and GDK as well since those are the only ones which support png rendering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem comes from the fact that you are actually plotting nothing to your plot because x is empty. The step you use is too large in your [np.arange](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html). The third argument to `np.arange` is the step or increment use to build the array, unlike matlab [linspace](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html) function, for which the third argument is the number of points generated.

Try this instead:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0,2*np.pi,0.01)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x,y)


plt.savefig('Sine.png')
```

which results in this png (in Ubuntu 15.04, Python 2.7.9, matplotlib 1.4.2):

[image]

**update(2015-07-28):**

Regarding the `backend`, as suggested in the [pyplot documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig):

> If format is None and fname is a string, the output format is deduced from the extension of the filename. If the filename has no extension, the value of the rc parameter savefig.format is used.
>
> If fname is not a string, remember to specify format to ensure that the correct backend is used.

So maybe to explicitly specifying an extension to the file will help solving the issue regarding the `backend` (I've updated the code accordingly). By default, the backend `TkAgg` is used on my machine, so there was no problem plotting with the default settings.

Comment: Oh haha, thank you I didn't catch that! While this works I do have to change the backend to agg to get the png to render.

Comment: @user3760593  Ah ok. By default, the backend `TkAgg` is used to plot with matplotlib on my system. What happen if you explicitly specify the format of the file like that: `plt.savefig('Sine.png')`, without changing the backend?

Comment: Thank you again! Specifying the format output in plt.savefig does solve the issue of backends.